# how can i get action from Submit button in uiwebview in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I want to filter action when i tap submit button in webarchive file using UIWEBVIEW. especially the ACTION URL link

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a webview wants to load something, it will call

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```